# Why numpy.histrogram command is giving blank graph?

Tags: matplotlib

I am using following code to plot histogram. But my plot is blank. Can someone please point out my mistake? I tried to use normed=True and also increased amount of data but still getting a blank graph.

```
`x=[29.205724, 1.08230571, 4.37276186, 7.89488022, 6.2904693]
hist,bins = np.histogram(x,bins=5)`
```

Comment: `numpy.histogram` does not produce a plot. Did you mean to use `pyplot.hist` instead?

Comment: So if I have to plot graph using above data and using np.histogram command what extra command should I give? If I use plt.histogram I don't even need to use np.histogram. I want to use data from np.histogram to plot graph. I want to plot probability on y-axis